# Pass two parameters to stored procedure and grab value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

First check my controller code below. Then also check the bottom picture which contains my stored procedure code in SQL Server Management Studio.

Now the issue is: my `PagedSearchedUserItems` procedure needs two `int` parameters and it will return output of few columns of data (you can see data sample from screen shot picture below).

In my controller, I am not getting idea how I can pass two parameters and get back that data in variable `Items`. Can you please fix my controller code to pass two parameters correctly, and grab all values on my variable "Items" ?

Controller code:

```
using (var ctx = new db_demoEntities())
{
    var Items = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SearchedUserItems>("EXEC PagedSearchedUserItems @TakeFrom",2).ToList<SearchedUserItems>();
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PagedSearchedUserItems
    @TakeFrom INT,
    @TakePerPage INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM SearchedUserItems 
    ORDER BY Id 
        OFFSET @TakeFrom ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT @TakePerPage ROWS ONLY;
END

PagedSearchedUserItems 2,5
```

[SQL Server Management Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxejm.png)

Comment: **Typo** alerts: it's a **stored** procedure - as in **stored** inside SQL Server (has nothing to do with a "store" ...) - and it's "below" - (not "bellow") one "l" is **quite enough**

Comment: bro u was English teacher back in the day? anyway your fix appreciated. Can you answer my question? Please...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that. This code should work fine with passing two parameters. I am assuming that "SearchedUserItems" object is maching your Data model.

```
using (var ctx = new db_demoEntities())
{
object[] xparams = {
new SqlParameter("@TakeFrom", 2),
new SqlParameter("@TakePerPage", 5)};

var Items = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SearchedUserItems>("EXEC PagedSearchedUserItems @TakeFrom, @TakePerPage", xparams).ToList<SearchedUserItems>();
}
```